# Unicode URLs w/ jQuery Mobile in Safari (OS X & iOS)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, unicode, uri

I'm currently using jQuery Mobile to build a simple interface to a site that uses many non-ASCII URLs.

For example:

```
http://localhost:1234/static/日本語.html
```

This doesn't usually present any problems, and the same page can also be accessed using a percent encoding:

```
http://localhost:1234/static/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E.html
```

After loading jQuery Mobile in the page headers the links continue to work, but Safari on iOS 5.1.1 and Safari 5.1.7 on OS X display a percent encoding in the location bar that seems to be invalid:

```
http://localhost:1234/static/%E5,%9E.html
```

This is problematic because URLs can't be bookmarked or accessed directly (returning a 404). Chrome displays the URLs as intended.

Incidentally, "%E5,%9E" doesn't seem to match any common percent encodings for "日本語":
 [http://www.motobit.com/util/url-encoder.asp?data=日本語](http://www.motobit.com/util/url-encoder.asp?data=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E)

And finally, the page headers I'm using to load jQuery Mobile:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using raw IRIs in HTML links? Avoid this, the browser support just isn't there yet. Always use the URI-valid version (the percent encoding you have above), and modern browsers will still display the IRI version in the address bar.

Comment: And...that was the answer! Raw IRIs were working so well that I didn't realize there were still problems w/ browser support. Encoding the IRIs fixed the issue, and (as you suggested) Safari still displays the IRI version in the location bar. Thanks!